# Parse Xpath from Int

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, xpath

Tenho um scrapy rodando o for para trazer o dia e o link de algo. Ex:

```
t_day = div.xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first()
a_day = div.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
day = int(t_day)
if day > last_day:
    print(t_day, a_day)
```

E na execução retorna o erro:

> ```
> in parse
> day = int(t_day)
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
> ```

O que preciso fazer para resolver a execução?

Comment: Qual conteúdo da varíavel `t_day`?

Comment: o conteúdo executa valores .xpath

Comment: Eu sei, mas qual é a valor que está atribuído no momento que ele tenta parsear o int(t_day), pois o erro que está dando é que o conteúdo não é númerico.

Comment: Ta indo valor NoneType, acredito que esteja passando tipo Nulo mesmo

Comment: Você encontrou o problema, nulo não pode ser convertido pra inteiro.

Comment: como eu faço para tratar o nulo de comparação para inteiro ?

Comment: Você pode deixar um valor padrão pra ele: `int(0 if a is None else t_day)` você pode substituir o 0 pelo valor que você quer que seja padrão.

Comment: Valeu cara, executei aqui e deu certo ! vlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro acontece pois o valor da variável **t_day** é nulo, você pode usar um if ternário para resolver o problema, retornando um valor default caso a variável seja nula.

```
int(0 if a is None else t_day)
```